# Retrofit object returned as null

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I've built a RetroFitService to return some objects. In MainActivity I call the service with a simple button click. I seem to be getting some kind of object, but I don't feel it's actually being returned from the REST API that I specified. It shows up in the debugger but its attributes are null:

```
bFetch.setOnClickListener(v -> {
 v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.image_click));
 RetrofitService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(RetrofitService.class, RetrofitService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
 service.getPosts()
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(new Subscriber < Post > () {
  @Override
  public final void onCompleted() {
   Log.e("RetrofitService", "Retrofit Request Completed!");
  }

  @Override
  public final void onError(Throwable e) {
   Log.e("RetrofitService", e.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public final void onNext(Post post) {
   if (post != null) {
    // TODO: Some object is returned but its properties are null
    Log.e("RetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + post);
    Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object Id: " + post.getObjectId());
    mCardAdapter.addData(post);
   } else {
    Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
   }

  }

 });

});

}
```

[image]

**Service:**

```
public interface RetrofitService {

 String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";

 @Headers({
  "X-Parse-Application-Id: asdf",
  "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: asdf"
 })
 @GET("/classes/Post")
 Observable < Post > getPosts();

 /*curl -X GET \
         -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: asdf" \
         -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: asdf" \
 https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Post*/

}
```

The curl works just fine. I'm not getting any errors. What could be going wrong? Is my `@GET` method incorrect somehow?`

For completion, here is the **ServiceFactory** class:

```
public class ServiceFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a retrofit service from an arbitrary class (clazz)
     * @param clazz Java interface of the retrofit service
     * @param endPoint REST endpoint url
     * @return retrofit service with defined endpoint
     */
    public static <T> T createRetrofitService(final Class<T> clazz, final String endPoint) {
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(endPoint)
                .build();
        T service = restAdapter.create(clazz);

        return service;
    }
}
```

And my **build.gradle** because I'm aware that there are inconsistencies across all the different Retrofit versions:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    /* ReactiveX */
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.17'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.0'

    /* Retrofit */
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

    /* OkHttp3 */
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'

    /* RecylerView */
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

    /* CardView */
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

    /* Parse */
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'

}
```

**Post Class:**

```
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "Post";

    private String objectId;
    private String text;

    public Post(String objectId) {
        this.setObjectId(objectId);
    }

    public static String getClassName() {
        return CLASS_NAME;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    private void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
```

**Curl Response:**

```
>     https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Post/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   259  100   259    0     0    360      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   395{"results":[{"objectId":"ktEfgr1pFt","text":"Hello World.","createdAt":"2017-08-14T14:07:52.826Z","updatedAt":"2017-08-14T14:07:52.826Z"},{"objectId":"Mmh8l9gjCk","text":"Hello?","createdAt":"2017-08-14T15:19:01.515Z","updatedAt":"2017-08-14T15:19:03.743Z"}]}
```

**FINAL UPDATE:** I changed the `onNext()` method of the `RetrofitService` to pass into the CardAdapter, although that isn't shown here and surpasses the scope of the question.

```
@Override
public final void onNext(PostResponse postResponse) {
 if (postResponse != null) {
  // TODO: Some object is returned but its properties are null
  Log.e("RetrofitService", "Objects successfully added to RecyclerView Adapter.");
  Log.e("RetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + postResponse.getResults());
  Log.e("RetrofitService", "Text " + postResponse.getResults().get(0).getText());

  mCardAdapter.addData(postResponse);
  //
 } else {
  Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
 }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to fetch objects which are created by parse sdk. Make sure that your data structure of Post class matches what the endpoint is returning (use String for example).

And btw I would mask the url and credentials from the question.

Comment: I updated my question with the Post object. I don't really see a problem with it...

Comment: Could you also provide the json response from 
curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: asdf" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: asdf" https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Post

Comment: Updated again with json response.

Comment: I update my comment. The mistake is obvious now: you should create a wrapper class for the wrapper object which contains a list of Post objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following class in RetrofitService

```
@GET("/classes/Post")
Observable <PostResponse> getPosts();
```

PostResponse wrapper class

```
public class PostResponse {
    private List<Post> results;

    public List<Post> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Post> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

Comment: You guys are making it hard for me to reward the question. Both answers definitely helped. And yeah I did have to wrap the List I was returning in the class you provided here.

Comment: I think Torsten deserves a reward more than me. He answered first :)

Comment: Cool, but I think the answer should also include the part about the trailing slash so other people get that bit. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 1):

According to the update of your question you are receiving not a single object, but an object with a collection of `Post` objects.

So you need to add one more class:

```
public class Results {
   List<Post> results = ArrayList<>()
}
```

Then update your API interface method to return `Observable<Results>`:

```
Observable <Results> getPosts();
```

And inside the subscription you can finally access the `Result` object with the `results` field, containing the collection of `Post` objects.

---

A minor mistake is that your endpoint base URL has trailing slash:

```
String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
```

At the same time your API method has slash at the beginning of the path:

```
 @GET("/classes/Post")
 Observable < Post > getPosts();
```

*As far as I remember* with retrofit you should have either trailing slash in endpoint  address or beginning slash in API methods, otherwise this may not work properly.

This one should be correct:

```
String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"; // No slash here
@GET("/classes/Post") // Keep slash here, or vice verse
Observable<Results> getPosts();
```

---

Just some comments on your dependencies section:

Is there any special reason you are using `io.reactivex:rxandroid` version `0.23.0` while the latest stable is `1.2.1`?

You don't need `io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.17` dependency, as retrofit 1.9.0 already depends on rxjava 1.0.0

Comment: Thanks. You're right about the trailing slash. I cleaned up my dependencies. I'm only using 0.23.0 because that's where I've had it working (in a slightly different implementation) in a previous project. Seems like Retrofit has gone through a ton of changes recently. Unfortunately I'm still getting null object attributes. Maybe it's because I'm returning a list and not processing it as such, as indicated by Torsten.

Comment: Just a note it seems that ``RetrofitService.getPosts: URL path "classes/Post" must start with '/'.``, according to my Monitor.

Comment: @santafebound You posted the json response body and I updated my answer. You deserialyze a collection of Post objects wrapped into another object within the result field into a single Post object. That is the real mistake. Not a trailing slash.